# How to delete an SSIS package that has been deployed to the file system

Tags: file, ssis, system, package, deployment

Is it as simple as deleting the file, or do I have to do anything to de-register it before I delete it.

Does the deployment process do anything more than copy it to the "Packages" folder.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does register the SSIS packages on the target SSIS server.  If you delete the packages from the file system, you would leave the registration information on the SSIS server.

The best way to remove a deployed SSIS package from a server is to use SQL Server Management Studio, Object Explorer and connect to the SSIS server (note that your server type is Integration Services, not Database Engine, in the connection dialog.)  Navigate to Stored Packages > File System to find your project.  Right-click the project and select Delete.

By the way, if you already deleted the files from the file system, you'll get errors when deleting from the SSIS server.  You can redeploy the SSIS packages and then delete from the SSIS server.

Comment: What if I haven't imported them yet?

Comment: Once they no longer show up under Stored Packages -> File System, is it safe to delete them from the file system?

Comment: If the files are not imported yet, then you won't see them in SSMS Object Explorer.  The delete from SSMS Object Explorer will also delete the file(s) from the file system as well.

Comment: I imported a package, and then deleted, it stayed in the file system.